# how to detect palindrome word using strcmp

Tags: dev-c++

Hye, I would really appreciate if anyone could answer this. The question is:

Write a program which will read a string of maximum 100 characters and rewrite its characters in reverse order. For example, the word GOOD should be written as DOOG and madam as madam. Check for palindrome words.
(A palindrome is a word whose meaning may be interpreted the same way in either forward or reverse direction)

Sample output:

Input your word: good
Reversed: doog
It is not a palindrome word

Input your word: madam
Reversed: madam`
It is a palindrome word

here is my source code :

```
> #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 100    
int main()
{
    char word[SIZE];
    int length,x,result;
    printf ("Input your word : ");
    gets(word);
    printf ("Reversed: ");
    puts (strrev(word)) ;
    length = strlen (word);
    for (x=0; x<length; x++)
    {
        result= strcmp (strrev(word),word));
        if (result==0)
            printf("It's a palindrome word!");
        else 
            printf ("It's not a palindrome word!");


    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, my source code stated above only managed to reverse the word but **not be able to detect the correct palindrome word.** Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to generate the reverse word, just compare the characters :

```
bool isPalindrom(char word[], int sizeOfWord){
    int j=sizeOfWord-1;
    for (int i=0 ; i<sizeOfWord ; i++){
        if(word[i] != word[j]){
            return false;
        }
        j--;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    char word[] = {'m', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'm'};
    int sizeOfWord = sizeof(word)/sizeof(word[0]);
    printf("%d", isPalindrom(word, sizeOfWord));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed some errors and worked ,I deleted for loop and fixed strcmp function

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you earned 15 reputation , I will satisfied , if you vote up to my answer ;)

Comment: It works! No more syntax error but still it can't differentiate between a palindrome word and a non palindrome word. Everytime i execute any word, the compiler will detect it as a palindrome word. And as required by the question, the user are allowed to input any word. Hopefully someone could answer this . Thanks!

Comment: I changed the code, now it working for every condition

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. Will vote for your answer when I managed to reach 15 reputation :D